# Create a parsable JSON file for android application

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get a list of images in a json file I have on my webserver with my android application. But they are not being read, I must have made some mistake, probably in my json file.

I'm trying to create a .Json file my application can read, one of my experimental JSON files is listed below, but it's not working.

Since I'm not very experienced with Json I was wondering if somebody else might know how to create a JSON file my application can parse.

My experimental json file:

```
{
"Wallpaper": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Clouds",
        "thumburl": "http://url.com/images/Pages/Apps/apps.png",
        "previewurl": "http://url.com/images/Pages/Apps/apps.png",
        "url": "http://url.com/images/Pages/Apps/apps.png",
        "text": "Sky"
    }
]
}
```

And my code:

```
 import someimportsandotherstuff

 import de.dan_nrw.android.scroid.Wallpaper;


 public final class JsonWallpaperParser implements IWallpaperParser {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of JsonWallpaperParser.
 */
JsonWallpaperParser() {
    super();
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see de.dan_nrw.boobleftboobright.IWallpaperParser#parse(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public List<Wallpaper> parse(String data) throws ParseException {
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
        List<Wallpaper> wallpapers = new ArrayList<Wallpaper>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonWallpaper = array.getJSONObject(i);

            wallpapers.add(new Wallpaper(jsonWallpaper.getString("id"),
                                         jsonWallpaper.getString("title"),
                                         URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("thumburl")),
                                         URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("previewurl")),
                                         URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("url")),
                                         jsonWallpaper.getString("text")));
        }

        return wallpapers;
    }
    catch (JSONException ex) {
        throw new ParseException(ex.getMessage(), 0);
    }           
}
 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That JSON you listed does not evaluate, missing commas

Comment: Thank you for helping me, It would be great if your could say where I'm missing them or where I've made any mistakes

Comment: @Mark029348 What do you want ...are the below posts doesn't answer your question? Let me know if can help you

Comment: No, unfortunately they are not. The posts are saying how to make a correct JSON file, not how to make a JSON file that my application can read. They probably didn't even read my java code, only the JSON.

Comment: @Mark029348 your edited json is correct... I have checked it in JSONLint.com, but you are not parsing properly ..check my answer

Comment: @Mark 029348 look at my answer it will help you in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then your json should be like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Clouds",
        "thumburl": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png",
        "previewurl": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png",
        "url": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png",
        "text": "Sky"
    }
]
```

---

Your `JSONString` returning `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`
You should parse your json string like this

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray array=object.getJSONArray("wallpaper");
List<Wallpaper> wallpapers = new ArrayList<Wallpaper>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonWallpaper = array.getJSONObject(i);

    wallpapers.add(new Wallpaper(jsonWallpaper.getString("id"),
                                 jsonWallpaper.getString("title"),
                                 URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("thumburl")),
                                 URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("previewurl")),
                                 URI.create(jsonWallpaper.getString("url")),
                                 jsonWallpaper.getString("text")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you to, this was the Answer I was the kind of answer I was looking for, but unfortunately, just as bobbake4's answer, it doesn't work, and I don't know why. I tried your code, and I formatted my JSON as in Josiah Hester's answer, but nothing.

Comment: @Mark029348 make sure that your `data` is not null and not working in the sense..what happened Let me now

Comment: My data not null? Could you explain this a little further, my code whole code should be correct, and it worked before, but I lost the JSON file, so I'm trying to create a new one (or a source that can read my experimental one ofcourse)

Comment: @Mark029348 Then your original json should be like above posted in answer

Comment: That's my whole problem, I don't have it, and thats why I'm trying to recreate it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I'll set a bounty on this question and give it to you, you earn it!

Comment: @Mark029348 No need...Good to know it works for you...You mark this as answer by clicking the right checkbox beside the answer

Comment: I know, I'll set a bounty in 2 days and then I will mark your answer (if it's possible to mark your answer now and give bounty afterwards, i'll do that)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is you're trying to create a JSONArray when your root element is a JSONObject.

This line is incorrect:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
```

You should change this to:

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray array = rootObject.optJSONArray("wallpaper");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I'm looking for. I've tested it, but for some reason This is not working to, and I would like to tell why, but I have no clue at all. I tried this, and I formatted my JSON as in Josiah Hester's answer, but nothing.

Comment: Does your catch block get called with a JSONException? If so what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: The exception will most likely tell you what the problem is, once you get the stack trace update your question with it.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON has syntax errors. A number of the lines are missing commas, e.g.

```
    "previewurl": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png"
    "url": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png"
```

Comment: I've edited it, but it doesn't work, probably made some other mistakes

Comment: you can try http://jsonlint.org to test your json for correctness. As well, how are you getting this json? building it yourself? If so, you shouldn't. There's plenty of libraries of all sorts of languages to do native->json->native translations for you.

Comment: I've reformulated my question, could you take a look again?

Answer (score 3):

Format your json like this:

```
{
    "wallpaper": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Clouds",
            "thumburl": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png", 
            "previewurl": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png", <--- You were missing a comma here
            "url": "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png", <-- and here
            "text": "Sky"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the future, you can use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com) to verify correctness.

Comment: I've tested it, it didn't work unfortunately, I think i've made some other mistakes to. I'll edit my question

Comment: I've reformulated my question, it would be great & helpfull if you could take a look again and share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Before parse any JSON string. create your JSON String like this

```
try {

   JSONObject wallpaper=new JSONObject();
   wallpaper.put("id", "1");
   wallpaper.put("title", "Clouds");
   wallpaper.put("thumburl", "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png");
   wallpaper.put("previewurl", "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png");
   wallpaper.put("url", "http://sherdle.com/images/Pages/Apps/Sherdleapps.png");
   wallpaper.put("text", "Sky");
   JSONArray wallpaer_array=new JSONArray();
   wallpaer_array.put(wallpaper);
   Log.d("json :",wallpaer_array.toString(0));

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**Logcat:**

```
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): [
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): {
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "id": "1",
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "thumburl": "http:\/\/sherdle.com\/images\/Pages\/Apps\/Sherdleapps.png",
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "text": "Sky",
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "title": "Clouds",
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "previewurl": "http:\/\/sherdle.com\/images\/Pages\/Apps\/Sherdleapps.png",
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): "url": "http:\/\/sherdle.com\/images\/Pages\/Apps\/Sherdleapps.png"
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): }
05-06 11:05:51.253: D/json :(434): ]
```